# Android multiple layout inflater, i can work only in the first

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater, inflate

i have several layout inflater in my code, which is necessary:

```
    for (String valori : timers_valori){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View menuLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_statistica, contenitore_statistiche, true);
        TextView nome=(TextView)menuLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer_testo_1);
        nome.setText(x+"");
        menuLayout.invalidate();
        x=x+1;
    }
```

(the code is trimmed)

it works, but it continue to edit the first layout, for example:

OUTPUT
ciao
...
...

INSTEAD I NEED
hello
hola
ciao

any idea? i think it's not linkin correctly the textview.

thanks!

Comment: have one textview and append text to the same. why inflate a new layout?

Comment: because the textview is only one small part of the code. i've written that it's a trim

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to iterate the id R.id.timer_testo_1 on each loop, as it is overriding the content of same TextView. Another tip is to get LayoutInflater outside of the for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add each view that generates the main view,

Example:

```
addView (nome);
```

You should do this in every cycle of the loop.

Your code would look like: :

```
for (String valori : timers_valori){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View menuLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_statistica, contenitore_statistiche, true);
    TextView nome=(TextView)menuLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer_testo_1);
    nome.setText(x+"");
    menuLayout.invalidate();
    x=x+1;
    addView(nome);
}
```

Comment: i'll try in a couple of hour, i'll let you know, thanks

Comment: addView needs to be linked to what? addView itself can't be, i need a view like main_view.addView

Comment: Linked to main view of activity @DFerra

Comment: but why you are adding nome instead of the principal menuLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply adding

```
nome.setId(x);
```

right after TextView declaration.